# Question regarding the statement of the Local Existence Theorem in Local Class Field Theory

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, local-field

Let $K$ be a non-archimedean local field. Then the local existence theorem states that the norm groups in $K^*$ are exactly the open subgroups of finite index.

Here what is meant by an 'open' subgroup of $K^*$? I am getting confused, and I would appreciate any clarification. Thank you.

Comment: A local field is a metric space. A metric space is a topological space (it has the notion of open set).

Comment: In the notes I am reading it talks about the 'norm topology' on $K^*$ which is coarser than the usual topology (the one I believe you are mentioning). And it is not clear to me which topology they are talking about when they talk about this result...

Comment: No doubt, somewhere in these notes, is a proof that the "norm topology" is the same as the usual topology.

Comment: Really?? it says 'In particular, $U_K$ is not open in $K^*$ for the norm topology, which is therefore coarser than the usual topology on $K^*$'

Comment: On page 23 after (7) of http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/CFT.pdf  Perhaps I am misunderstanding something...

Comment: See Theorem 5.1 in Milne's notes.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown : theorem 5.1 doesn't say at all that  the "norm topology" is the same as the usual topology. The OP is correct: the norm topology is coarser than the usual topology.

Comment: Even if the norm and usual topologies differ on $K^*$, they coincide on $O_K^*$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider the easy example where $K = \Bbb Q_p$. It has a topology, induced by the $p$-adic metric, namely $d(x,y) = |x-y|_p$, where $| \cdot |_p$ is the $p$-adic absolute value.

Then the subspace $K^{\times} \subset K$ has an induced topology, and a subset $U \subset K^{\times}$ is open iff it is the intersection of $K^{\times}$ with a union of open balls $B_{d}(x,r)$ for some $x \in K^{\times}, r>0$.

Then a subgroup $H \leq K^{\times}$ is open (with respect to the $p$-adic topology) of finite index iff it is a norm subgroup.

Comment: open with respect to the usual topology (induced by the one on $K$), I guess?

Comment: @JohnnyT. : yes

Comment: ok... thank you!